# Testing stalls after Chrome is opened by Selenium ChromeDriver in Serenity

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am attempting to write my first set of test cases using Serenity BDD 3.2.5, Java 11, Cucumber and Gradle 7.4.2. I am also using Chrome 120.0.6099.217 and the latest Chrome Driver (for Chrome 115 or newer)

My test compiles without error and even passes, but it doesn't actually conduct the test. There are no screenshots in the HTML generated report even though they are turned on. The test stops as soon as the browser window is open. I can see it open with the correct URL, but it just sits there. "Then I log in as user <USER_ID>" is where it stops.

Note: In the "I open a browser" step, I attempted using something like:

```
Open.browserOn().the(HomePage.class)
```

But it would NEVER open the browser. It would run all the tests, even say they passed but nothing would happen. That is why I am doing it manually with the selenium chrome driver.

**Here are my steps:**

```
package csd.uitests.stepdefinitions;

import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.matchers.WebElementStateMatchers.isVisible;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import ca.toronto.csd.uitests.business.ui.TargetList;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Click;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.*;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.waits.WaitUntil;
import ca.toronto.csd.uitests.util.UserPasswdEnum;

public class ViewSteps {

    @Before
    public void setTheStage() {
        OnStage.setTheStage(new OnlineCast());
    }
       
    @When("I Open a Browser")
    public void OpenBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips");
        options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.6099.217 Safari/537.36"); 
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        String strURL= "HTTPS://myurl.com";
        driver.get(strURL);       
    }  

    @Then("I login as user {string}")
    public void callLoginGetAPI(String userId) {
        
        WaitUntil.the(TargetList.USERNAME, isVisible());
        String userPassword = UserPasswdEnum.valueOf("USER_" + userId).getUserPasswd();
        Clear.field(TargetList.USERNAME);
        Enter.theValue(userId).into(TargetList.USERNAME);
        Clear.field(TargetList.PASSWORD);
        Enter.theValue(userPassword).into(TargetList.PASSWORD);
        Click.on(TargetList.LOGINBUTTON);
    }
```

**
My list of 'targets':**

```
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.targets.Target;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class TargetList {
    
    //login page
    static By USERNAME_FIELD = By.name("userId");
    static By PASSWORD_FIELD = By.name("password");
    static By LOGIN_BUTTON = By.id("Login");
    static By RESET_BUTTON = By.id("Reset");
    static By ERROR_MESSAGE = By.id("msg");
    static By Error_message_common = By.xpath("//*[@id='loginTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td/span");

    public static Target USERNAME = Target.the("username").located(USERNAME_FIELD);
    public static Target PASSWORD = Target.the("password").located(PASSWORD_FIELD);
    public static Target LOGINBUTTON = Target.the("login button").located(LOGIN_BUTTON);
```

**Here is my Serenity.conf file:**

```
webdriver {
  driver = chrome
  "goog:chromeOptions" { args = ["remote-allow-origins=*"] }
  wait {
    for {
        timeout = 30000
        }
    }
  timeouts {
    implicitlywait = 30000
  }
}

#TODO Add this property to CMD runtime later
headless.mode = false

chrome {
    capabilities {
        acceptSslCerts = true
        handlesAlerts = true
        acceptInsecureCerts = true
        networkConnectionEnabled = true
    }
}

gecko.firefox.options = "{"args": ["-headless"]}"
serenity.activate.firebugs = false

chrome.switches = """--start-maximized;--test-type;--no-sandbox;--ignore-certificate-errors;--incognito;
        --disable-popup-blocking;--disable-default-apps;--disable-extensions-file-access-check;
        --disable-infobars;--disable-gpu;--disable-web-security;-–allow-file-access-from-files;
        --whitelisted-ips;remote-allow-origins=*;
        --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.6099.217 Safari/537.36"""

# Appears at the top of the reports
serenity.project.name = "Selenium UI Automated Acceptance Tests"

#
# Define drivers for different platforms. Serenity will automatically pick the correct driver for the current platform
#
drivers {
  windows {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe"
    webdriver.gecko.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/geckodriver.exe"
  }
  mac {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/chromedriver"
    webdriver.gecko.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/geckodriver"
  }
  linux {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/chromedriver"
    webdriver.gecko.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/geckodriver"
  }
}

untrusted.certificates = true
serenity.take.screenshots = FOR_EACH_ACTION
serenity.full.page.screenshot.strategy = true

#
# This section defines environment-specific configuration for different environments.
# You can define normal Serenity properties, such as webdriver.base.url, or custom ones
#
environments {
    default {
        webdriver.base.url = "MYURL"
    }
}


If there is any other code/info I can include to help complete the picture let me know. I am looking any and all suggestions on what may be going wrong. But you may need to ELI5 (Explain it to me like I am 5) because I am super new at this!
```

I was expecting to see screenshots in the report and be able to watch the browser window complete the laid-out steps.

Comment: I turned on crash report tracking in Chrome and visited: chrome://crashes. No crash reported. I changed the browser from Chrome to Firefox, EXACT same thing, test stalls as soon as the browser is opened. I have also updated all my Selenium jar files to 4.16.1.  Another thing to note, I have another set of tests that are set up with Ant instead of Gradle on my system that works perfectly. It uses the same ChromeDriver (I know because I copied it from the webdriver/windows folder of the working instance to the non-working instance) And the same exact version of Chrome.